# char splitting and parsing

Tags: c, parsing, strtok, split

so i'm attempting to setup a function that will correctly parse the following type of input (note that this input is jibberish just to try and illustrate my example)

```
"./test script";ls -a -o;mkdir "te>st";ls > somefile.txt
```

Where each command is separated by a ';' and each argument is separated by whitespace ' ' except in cases where they are wrapped in "" in which case they should be treated as literal or whole. IE the output I would want from this is

cmd : "./test script"

cmd : ls args[2] {-a, -o}

cmd : mkdir args[1] { "te>st" }

cmd : ls args[2] {>, somefile.txt}

I've tried splitting it via ; first, then via ' ' but the first example fails (wrapped in "" so should be considered whole), i'm having some trouble with c as i'm not really familiar with the language, could anyone help? this is what I have so far

```
    // Commands split with ; 
    char *cmdSplitToken = strtok(srcPointer, ";");

    // Store commands seperately so we can deal with them one by one
    while(cmdSplitToken != NULL) {      
        cmds[cmdCount++] = cmdSplitToken;
        cmdSplitToken = strtok(NULL, ";");
    }

    // Loop over commands and gather arguments
    for(int i = 0; i < cmdCount; i++) {     
        // args split with ' '
        char *argSplitToken = strtok(cmds[i], " "); 
        int argCount = 0;
        while(argSplitToken != NULL) {      
            printf("arg %s\n", argSplitToken);
            argCount++;
            argSplitToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roll your own `strtok` and check for quotes in there. (Your example string doesn't contain any ';' inside quotes, so perhaps I am misunderstanding the entire issue :)

Anyway, here is my take on a rough version of `strtok` that works similar, except that it only accepts one single token character instead of a string (but if necessary, that's easily added) and it does meta-parsing on the following:

- strings that start with `"` are matched up to a closing `"`
- strings that start with `'` are matched up to a closing `'`
- *any* individual character can be escaped by prepending a `\`

An unmatched `"` and `'` will simply match all up to the end of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *get_token (char *input_str, char separator)
{
    static char *last_pos;

    if (input_str)
        last_pos = input_str;
    else
        input_str = last_pos;

    if (last_pos && *last_pos)
    {
        while (*last_pos)
        {
            if (*last_pos == separator)
            {
                *last_pos = 0;
                last_pos++;
                return input_str;
            }
            if (*last_pos == '\"')
            {
                last_pos++;
                while (*last_pos && *last_pos != '\"')
                    last_pos++;
            } else
            if (*last_pos == '\'')
            {
                last_pos++;
                while (*last_pos && *last_pos != '\'')
                    last_pos++;
            } else
            if (*last_pos == '\\' && last_pos[1])
            {
                last_pos++;
            }
            last_pos++;
        }
        return input_str;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void main (void)
{
    char str[] = "\"./test; script\";ls -a\\;b -o;mkdir \"te>st\";ls > 'some;file.txt'";
    char *cmdSplitToken = get_token (str, ';');

    while (cmdSplitToken != NULL)
    {
        printf("arg %s\n", cmdSplitToken);
        cmdSplitToken = get_token (NULL, ';');
    }
}
```

This only fixes the first half of your command parsing. The second part can be handled with this same routine, or -- as I understand it -- with bog standard `strtok`.

By the way, the `static char` inside my routine makes it **not re-entrant** -- do *not* use it with alternating strings. (Possibly you already knew that, because you also avoid it in your own code.)

Comment: Just thought of this: 'any individual character can be escaped by prepending a \' only works *outside* of ".." and '..' quoted strings. To make it also escape inside strings it needs a bit more code. Personally, I'm also partial to the alternative method `".."".."` -- double-up to get a single one.

Comment: That's almost perfect for my needs, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the use of `strtok` when you have to deal with complex rules (fields with emebedded double quotes), make your own function or use some library, I suggest to take a look to [libcsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/?source=dlp), a small and simple library written in pure ANSI C89.